# correct way of EMDK 3.1 deInitialization Scanner

Tags: barcode-scanner, motorola

I wrote sample app using EMDK 3.0 for deInitialization Scanner and what is the correct way of it?

```
scanner.cancelRead();
scanner.disable();
scanner.removeDataListener(this);
scanner.removeStatusListener(this);
scanner.release();
```

I want to ordered the above steps..

Answer (score 0):

There is a complete sample code available at: https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-2659

According to the [docs](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-2590) the correct procedure appears to be:

```
scanner.cancelRead();
scanner.disable();
```